Plugin Dynamics CRM online - context.GetBusinessEntity
Retrieving opportunity entity attributes using context.GetBusinessEntity which goes to retrieve them from output parameters through plugin in CRM Dynamics online but sometimes one account field is being retrieved other times it is not coming. Why
This Field is not present on the form. But it is retrieved for other opportunities when that field has data without any problem , only for this record it is not working.

share your code and describe exactly what you want to achieve
